# Adding Extremely Large Numbers in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, math

I'm having trouble adding large numbers together like

```
8767657654576576546675676567656765676576567676789876567898765456897654567876545678765456787656789876567898765678000000000022222222222222222
```

and

```
8765487654876548765487654876547876545678765478765478654567876567876545678765456786
```

do you know how this is possible to get a normal large plain text number without getting the error: `answer is either too small or too large to convert to decimal`

My Code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim value1 As String = message.Text
    Dim value2 As String = mykey.Text
    Dim total = Convert.ToDecimal(value1) + Convert.ToDecimal(value2)
    sum.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", total)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

Comment: is it an import or do i add it to dim total = System.Numerics.BigInteger(value1) + System.Numerics.BigInteger(value2)

Comment: It's a class, so you'd import `System.Numerics` and then use it via `new BigInteger`

Comment: can i suggest accepting answers that helped you. If nothing else, you get some rep too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET 4.0. onwards)

Add this import to your code:

```
Imports System.Numerics
```

For values greater than `Int64` you will need to use the [byte array constructer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`BigInteger.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "If you use the Parse method to round-trip the string representation
>   of a BigInteger value that was output by the ToString method, you
>   should use the BigInteger.ToString(String) method with the "R" format
>   specifier to generate the string representation of the BigInteger
>   value. Otherwise, the string representation of the BigInteger
>   preserves only the 50 most significant digits of the original value,
>   and data may be lost when you use the Parse method to restore the
>   BigInteger value."

Comment: Dosent seem to work Mitch, i imported what you said and added this:           
        Dim value1 As String = message.Text
        Dim value2 As String = mykey.Text
        Dim number As BigInteger = BigInteger.Pow(UInt64.MaxValue, 3)
        sum.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", number)

Comment: im using VS express 2012

Comment: "If you use the Parse method to round-trip the string representation of a BigInteger value that was output by the ToString method, you should use the BigInteger.ToString(String) method with the "R" format specifier to generate the string representation of the BigInteger value. Otherwise, the string representation of the BigInteger preserves only the 50 most significant digits of the original value, and data may be lost when you use the Parse method to restore the BigInteger value."

Comment: ok i guess that makes sense, but i still cant import numerics, error: dosent contain any public member or cannot be found. its built with .net 4.5 in VS 2012

Comment: ? i still cant import it

Comment: My Project>References>Add>Assemblies>Framework>Tick "System.Numerics"